# Как сделать анимированный placeholder?

Tags: javascript, html, css

В статье на хабре http://habrahabr.ru/post/260929/ в пункте 5 (про анимацию) показан пример анимации плейсхолдера.
Поля сами заполняются информацией, показывая пользователю что надо делать с формой.
Интересная штука, хочу сделать также. Гуглил весь день, ничего дельного не нашел.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто делал такое?

Comment: Не понимаю зачем? Кажется пользователь увидав, что форма сама заполняется будет просто ждать. Не совсем понятен ход ваших мыслей. Используйте JQuery и с задержкой в секунду добавляйте значение в атрибут placeholder определенного inputa. Сами значения хранить следует в неком массиве, после когда все значения заполнены в первом input перейти к следующему, и т.д. Когда все input-ы заполнятся очистить их и проводить с начала. Элементарно вроде бы пробуйте, будет код - поможем.

Comment: Там заполнение формы на видео записано, а не плейсхолдер.

Answer (score 4):

Решение на jQuery (не тестировал, но суть думаю ясна):

```
i = 0;
default = [['name', ['I', 'v', 'a', 'n']], ...];

// i - индекс элемента который меняем
function anim(i){
    if(i < default.length)
    {
        var text = $('input#'+default[i][0]).attr("placeholder");
        if (default[i][1].length == text.length){
            i++;
            anim(i);
        }
        else {
            text += default[i][1][text.length];
            $('input#'+default[i][0]).attr("placeholder", text);
        }
    }
    else {
        // очищаем все placeholder-ы
        i = 0;
        for(j=0; j<default.length; j++){
            $('input#'+default[i][0]).attr("placeholder", "");
        }
    }
}

// запускаем метод каждую секунду
var timerId = setInterval( anim(i), 1000);
// что бы выключить clearInterval(timerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input {background: url(image.gif)} анимированная картинка
input:focus {background: none;} убираем ее при вводе или заменяем на другую
```

Comment: Я считаю, что изображений, особенно в крупных проектах, стоит избегать либо их количество  сводить к минимуму. Так что вариант на чистом js, предложенный выше в комментарии или ниже в ответе - будет в разы лучше кучи картинок, если много полей в форме, в частности

Comment: @ГенераторКачества, если вам нужен только текст - да, но это не работать при отключенном js-е (что бывает довольно часто) и будет не актуален при использовании картинок, которые есть в примере который вы привели.

Comment: Нужно сделать проверку на активность js и, если он выключен, использовать ваш способ. Так будет разумнее